# Is there a way to overwrite a border CSS class

Tags: html, css

I have this rule

```
input{
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4XST/)

which is needed on most of the site but is messing up some button styling...I thought that adding border: none would overwrite this but it didnt. I cant remove the input styling because its needed sitewide...any workarounds

Comment: Seems to work for me, border is hidden. What browser are u using?

Comment: If you remove the input style for   border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
you will see the way i want the button to look....but border none doesnt work

Comment: I checked it in Firefox and IE and there is no border.

Comment: No the problem is not the border its that i want it to look like a button and the border from the css above is not making it look like a button

Comment: @Trace So what's wrong in doing something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S4XST/10/)?

Comment: -1: It's not clear from the question what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I dont want any border.....but I cant remove the CSS above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `:not` selector to skip the specific inputs whose default borders you want to keep.

```
input:not(#submit-me) {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4XST/2/

Perhaps you should consider improving the border as well instead of just using the default.

Comment: @WesleyMurch maybe I misinterpreted his question, but it seems that he doesn't want to hide the border for `#submit-me`, he just doesn't want it to use the `1px solid #e5e5e5` rule

Answer (score 0):

The border isn't being shown in your fiddle, which is correct.

CSS has very clear rules on the priority given to selectors. An ID-level selector has higher priority than a tag-level selector, so `#submit-me` should override `input`.

This is exactly what is happening in your fiddle, and exactly what you want to happen, so I can't quite see what the problem is.